# Keep Image from Drawing Outside Game Area

Tags: pygame

I was playing around with a pygame tutorial ([link](http://usingpython.com/animation/) for those interested).  One thing the tutorial has you do is create a cloud that crosses the screen.  Now, the game has a small bit bar at the bottom which is used for information and is outside the game area.  The problem is that the cloud is drawn outside the game area, so you see the cloud cross over the user information.  I am new to this, so I am not sure what I need to do or what question to ask to fix this.  Thanks.

Wade

Here is the code I am using:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.display.set_caption('M I N E C R A F T -- 2 D')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('player.png'))

fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

#constants representing colours
BLACK = (0,   0,   0  )
BROWN = (153, 76,  0  )
GREEN = (0,   255, 0  )
BLUE  = (0,   0,   255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

#cloud position
cloudx = -200
cloudy = 0

#constants representing the different resources
DIRT  = 0
GRASS = 1
WATER = 2
COAL  = 3
CLOUD = 4

#a dictionary linking resources to textures
textures =   {
                DIRT   : pygame.image.load('dirt.png'),
                GRASS  : pygame.image.load('grass.png'),
                WATER  : pygame.image.load('water.png'),
                COAL   : pygame.image.load('coal.png'),
                CLOUD  : pygame.image.load('cloud.png')
            }

inventory =   {
                DIRT   : 0,
                GRASS  : 0,
                WATER  : 0,
                COAL   : 0
            }

#useful game dimensions
TILESIZE  = 20
MAPWIDTH  = 30
MAPHEIGHT = 20

#the player image
PLAYER = pygame.image.load('player.png')
#the position of the player [x,y]
playerPos = [0,0]

#a list of resources
resources = [DIRT,GRASS,WATER,COAL]
#use list comprehension to create our tilemap
tilemap = [ [DIRT for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT) ] 

#set up the display
pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE + 50))

#add a font for our inventory
INVFONT = pygame.font.Font('FreeSansBold.ttf', 18)

#loop through each row
for rw in range(MAPHEIGHT):
    #loop through each column in that row
    for cl in range(MAPWIDTH):
        #pick a random number between 0 and 15
        randomNumber = random.randint(0,15)
        #if a zero, then the tile is coal
        if randomNumber == 0:
            tile = COAL
        #water if the random number is a 1 or a 2
        elif randomNumber == 1 or randomNumber == 2:
            tile = WATER
        elif randomNumber >= 3 and randomNumber <= 7:
            tile = GRASS
        else:
            tile = DIRT
        #set the position in the tilemap to the randomly chosen tile
        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile

while True:

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)    

    #get all the user events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #if the user wants to quit
        if event.type == QUIT:
            #and the game and close the window
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        #if a key is pressed
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #if the right arrow is pressed
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1:
                #change the player's x position
                playerPos[0] += 1
            if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
                #change the player's x position
                playerPos[0] -= 1
            if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[1] > 0:
                #change the player's x position
                playerPos[1] -= 1
            if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < MAPHEIGHT -1:
                #change the player's x position
                playerPos[1] += 1
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                #what resource is the player standing on?
                currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                #player now has 1 more of this resource
                inventory[currentTile] += 1
                #the player is now standing on dirt
                tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = DIRT

            #placing dirt
            if (event.key == K_1):
                #get the tile to swap with the dirt
                currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                #if we have dirt in our inventory
                if inventory[DIRT] > 0:
                    #remove one dirt and place it
                    inventory[DIRT] -= 1
                    tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = DIRT
                    #swap the item that was there before
                    inventory[currentTile] += 1

    #loop through each row
    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        #loop through each column in the row
        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
            #draw the resource at that position in the tilemap, using the correct image
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]], (column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))

    #display the player at the correct position 
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(PLAYER,(playerPos[0]*TILESIZE,playerPos[1]*TILESIZE))

    #display the cloud
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[CLOUD].convert_alpha(),(cloudx,cloudy))
    #move the cloud to the left slightly
    cloudx+=1
    #if the cloud has moved past the map
    if cloudx > MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE:
        #pick a new position to place the cloud
        cloudy = random.randint(0,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE)
        cloudx = -200

    #display the inventory, starting 10 pixels in
    placePosition = 10
    for item in resources:
        #add the image
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[item],(placePosition,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+20))
        placePosition += 30
        #add the text showing the amount in the inventory
        textObj = INVFONT.render(str(inventory[item]), True, WHITE, BLACK)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textObj,(placePosition,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+20)) 
        placePosition += 50

    #update the display
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(24)
```

Comment: Are you sure you've drawn them in the right order? Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: I honestly don't know if I tried that or not.  I worked on this tutorial a while ago and then I deserted it.  I came back to it because I hated that I couldn't see what I had done wrong.  I certainly can see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit the cloud to the game area, you can set what is called a `clipping rectangle` ([docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_clip)). This cuts off anything that is blitted outside the rectangle.

Set it like this, *before* blitting the clouds:

```
clippingRect = Rect(0, 0, MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE)
DISPLAYSURF.set_clip(clippingRect)
```

This sets `x, y, width, height` of the clipping rect.

Then disable it like this *before* trying to blit the info-bar:

```
DISPLAYSURF.set_clip(None)
```

I recommend that you read the [pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/index.html) alongside any and every tutorial.

Your modified cloud drawing code might be like this:

```
clippingRect = Rect(0, 0, MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE)
DISPLAYSURF.set_clip(clippingRect)

#display the cloud
DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[CLOUD].convert_alpha(),(cloudx,cloudy))
#move the cloud to the left slightly
cloudx+=1
#if the cloud has moved past the map
if cloudx > MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE:
    #pick a new position to place the cloud
    cloudy = random.randint(0,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE)
    cloudx = -20

DISPLAYSURF.set_clip(None)
```

You should actually enable the clipping rect before drawing the game area and only disable it when you are ready to draw outside.

Comment: Amziraro, that did it.